# Dynamic form fields in flask.request.form

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I've looked through the documentation, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how the `request.form` object in Flask is populated.  [The documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.form) says that it's filled with parsed form data from POST or PUT requests, but my form is dynamic so I don't necessarily know what fields exist when the POST request is sent - though I want to make sure I add the information from these fields to the database.

Some of the fields in the form are always there, but there will also be any number of extra fields from a list of about 60.  How should I go about figuring out which of these additional fields are in the request and how should I get the data from them?

EDIT: My specific problem has been solved, but it's still worth asking how the request.form dictionary is populated.  I found out the hard way that if a checkbox input is unchecked, there is no key added to the dictionary under its name, and trying to get the value of a key that does not exist from the dictionary results in a rather confusing and cryptic `HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST` error.

Comment: Which values appear in request.form depend on which data the browser send. The decision not to send a key when a checkbox is unchecked is made by the browser, not by Flask.

Comment: I think it's best if you open new questions for the new questions you have.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`request.form` returns a `MultiDict` object. Basically, it means that for 1 key, you could have multiple values. If you want to test what your form POST looks like, just do a quick print statement as follows

```
f = request.form
for key in f.keys():
    for value in f.getlist(key):
        print key,":",value
```

If you read the documentation for MultiDict, it says

"A MultiDict is a dictionary subclass customized to deal with multiple values for the same key which is for example used by the parsing functions in the wrappers. **This is necessary because some HTML form elements pass multiple values for the same key.**"

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict

Comment: I'd like to say (contribute) that, at a first glance, it's a little bit difficult to understand how the `request.form` is parsed just like a normal Python dictionary (although it returns a kind of `dict` with `tuples` if you try to print `f`), but the answer makes a lot of sense, specially regarding the example and also the definition of Flask MultiDict. Thanks a lot, #codegeek :).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I fixed calling the get method of ImmutableMultiDict.

Here's my code for a 'is_delivery' fieldname:

```
 if form_data.get('is_delivery', False) == 'on':
    is_delivery = 1
else:
    is_delivery = 0
```