# Python Flask - Receive data from form with multiple textboxes

Tags: python, flask

I am generating a web page form a sql query that returns several rows.  Im displaying them in a html table with 1 column being a text box.  I loop trough the sql results for each new line, the textbox fields all end up having the same name.

When clicking the submit button i am only recieving the one value from the first textbox.

Here is the HTML im using

```
<form action="/commit_changes" method=post>
    <ul class=naming>
  <h2>{{ Overview }}</h2>
    {% for entry in sensor_names %}
        <li>{{ entry.sensor_add|safe }}
        <input type="text" name="sensor_name" value={{ entry.sensor_name|safe }}>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="del">
        <li> <br> </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Commit Changes">
</form>
```

Here is the python code in flask:

```
@app.route('/commit_changes', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def commit_changes():
    print(request.form['sensor_name'])
    return redirect('settings')
```

Im having a guess that the only way to send the data back to python is some sort of javascript to loop through the textboxes and send them one at a time.  This is where im stuck :), hope someone can point me in the right direction.
CD

Comment: Why not give each a unique `name`? e.g., `<input name="sensor_name{{ entry.id }}"`

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the unique `name` attribute for the `input` text field.

```
<form action="/commit_changes" method=post>
        <ul class=naming>
      <h2>{{ Overview }}</h2>
        {% for entry in sensor_names %}
            <li>{{ entry.sensor_add|safe }}
            <input type="text" name="sensor_name{{entry.id}}" value={{ entry.sensor_name|safe }}>
            <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="del">
            <li> <br> </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Commit Changes">
    </form>
```

if you don't have `id` attribute for `sensor_names` object list.you could try `sensor_name{{forloop.counter}}` instead of `sensor_name{{entry.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

`request.form` is actually a custom "multi" dict object, provided by Werkzeug. It would have a custom `request.form.getlist('sensor_name')` field, or you could iterate with `request.form.items(multi=True)`.

It's not necessary to use a unique `name` attribute.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752301/dynamic-form-fields-in-flask-request-form